# How to interpret the effect of a predictor, if the inclusion of time renders the effect insignificant but AIC of the simple model is better?

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, aic

I research the recurrence of civil war in a sample of 18 countries that experienced civil war with annual longitudinal data over up to 29 years into the postwar period (for some countries less, as war ended e.g. only in 2000).

My hypothesis is that trust in security institutions (military & police) decreases the risk of war recurrence. War recurrence is coded as a binary variable, 0 = no war in that year, 1 = war in that year. Trust in security institutions is continuous on an index of 0 to 1 (maximum trust). I use mixed effects models in R and allow for a random intercept and slope per country. Even though time is not directly part of my hypothesis it might have an influence. Time is coded as the nth year after war termination, e.g. 1, 10 or 29.
The simple model with the predictor only yields a significant, positive effect. Inconveniently enough, this is contrary to my hypothesis as apparently higher trust increases the risk of war recurrence in my sample but I do have some ideas to explain it. This is the summary of the model:

```r
    Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
     Family: binomial  ( logit )
    Formula: ny_recurr_war_conf ~ conf_secu + (1 + conf_secu | country)
       Data: insti_a
    Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa")
    
         AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
       135.5    152.7    -62.7    125.5      228 
    
    Scaled residuals: 
        Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
    -1.1718 -0.4089 -0.0878 -0.0265  3.6373 
    
    Random effects:
     Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
     country (Intercept) 66.85    8.176         
             conf_secu   86.39    9.295    -1.00
    Number of obs: 233, groups:  country, 17
    
    Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
    (Intercept)  -11.298      3.654  -3.092  0.00199 **
    conf_secu     11.421      4.233   2.698  0.00697 **
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    
    Correlation of Fixed Effects:
              (Intr)
    conf_secu -0.993
    convergence code: 0
    boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

However, if I include time in the model, the effect disappears. Here is the second model:

```r
    Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
     Family: binomial  ( logit )
    Formula: ny_recurr_war_conf ~ conf_secu * postwar_year + (1 + conf_secu |      country)
       Data: insti_a
    
         AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
       137.7    161.9    -61.9    123.7      226 
    
    Scaled residuals: 
        Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
    -1.1688 -0.3619 -0.0944 -0.0262  3.9685 
    
    Random effects:
     Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
     country (Intercept) 52.06    7.215         
             conf_secu   65.56    8.097    -1.00
    Number of obs: 233, groups:  country, 17
    
    Fixed effects:
                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
    (Intercept)             -8.7079     3.8677  -2.251   0.0244 *
    conf_secu                8.4925     4.6269   1.835   0.0664 .
    postwar_year            -0.2211     0.1797  -1.230   0.2185  
    conf_secu:postwar_year   0.2598     0.2390   1.087   0.2770  
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    
    Correlation of Fixed Effects:
                (Intr) cnf_sc pstwr_
    conf_secu   -0.978              
    postwar_yer -0.480  0.502       
    cnf_sc:pst_  0.460 -0.531 -0.960
```

The question is, how to interpret the effect of trust in security institutions on war recurrence then? Originally, I planned to interpret the model with the best fit indicated by the AIC. This would be the model without time. But I know that to some extent the question of including time is of course a theoretical one. It is not part of my hypothesis, the effect would be interesting without knowing if it occurs sooner or later in the postwar period. But how would I imagine the influence of time given these results? Is it that in some years there is a rather large effect of trust, but in many others not and therefore, the effect of trust disappears when investigated with inclusion of time? The coefficient of trust in the 2nd model becomes substantially smaller, due to this? My supervisor said that he assumes the effect of trust might be driven by other variables, e.g., time as it makes the effect vanish? I do not fully understand this statement though (and he is now on vacation). If so, time would show a significant effect itself, wouldn't it? Do I even have to bother, as AIC does not indiciate any additional value of time as variable?

On another note, would it be advisable to allow random effects for postwar year per country as well when including it?

Any inspiration on any of these aspects are very welcome. Many thanks to all of you!

Comment: The first model is singular, and the 2nd model looks suspicuous too (correlation of -1.00 in the random structure). The data doesn't support correlated random effects.

Comment: Also, have you considered that a linear association with time may not be appropriate ?

Comment: Thanks, you're right, indeed the effect disappears if I only allow for a random intercept per country. How would I interpret this? We do not see a generalizable effect of trust in security institutions on war recurrence within countries? 
On another note: What if the effect was significant with random-intercept only, but not anymore with random slopes? I am generally having some troubles with interpreting models with vs. without random slopes. (Should I better post a new question for this? Sorry, I am new to this forum.)

Comment: And yes, a non-linear association might well be appropriate, but as I am doing many analyses in my study and do receive some effects, I thought to keep it simple for the timebeing. Thanks for your thoughts so far!

Comment: It is best to post a new question about that. All I would say for now is try not to be too concerned with p-values. P-values are not well-defined for mixed models so usually you will get an approximation. Try to focus on the effect size instead. As for keeping things simple, this is often a very good idea, however if you specify a linear association when the actal association is nonlinear, you are making a big mistake.